# Would black holes be present in all dimensions?

Tags: gravity, black-holes, string-theory, quantum-gravity, branes

I'm watching a video about string theory, in which the fact that gravity is weaker than the other forces is explained in that gravitons aren't bound to our universe directly, and can flow across various branes. If this is the case, would that not mean that singularities would be like fixed points across the various parallel universes?

Link: https://youtu.be/l5t8STlF_ns?t=19m59s

Answer (score 1):

> Would black holes be present in all dimensions?

If you mean whether there can be black holes in higher dimensions, yes, people do calculations about that all the time, see, e.g., [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/0801.3471) by Emparan and Reall.

In general, black holes in String theory might be something like a [black branes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_brane) or not even be singularities, but rather, e.g., "[fuzzballs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuzzball_(string_theory))".

> singularities would be like fixed points across the various parallel universes?

Maybe. Similar stuff has been proposed before, e.g., that apparent black holes [might actually be wormholes to other universes](https://www.newscientist.com/article/dn11745-could-black-holes-be-portals-to-other-universes/).

Comment: I mean that a black hole in our universe would be the same as one in a similar position in another universe

Comment: It's impossible to answer that. To start with, our current understanding of the universe is that it has no 'center', so how could someone talk about absolute position? Without absolute position, and that in both universes, we cannot talk about the black holes being "in similar positions". That's not to mention that all talk of other universes is at best speculative.

Comment: I suppose I mean would the same black hole exist across all dimensions?

Comment: The question of distinguishability  can be a very interesting one (even in a single universe). As far as I know, black holes have essentially the same status of elementary particles in QM, in the sense of being fully characterized by a few properties (such as mass and charge). Now, I guess you mean not the same, but linked to each other, and, then, I'd reiterate the part of my answer that mentions the possibility of them being actually wormholes.

Answer (score 0):

Not in general. Already in the low energy string theory, that is supergravity, singular solution in a lower dimensional space can lift to regular solutions in a higher dimensional space.

In particular, singularities covered by horizons in 4 dimensions, that is black holes, can lift to smooth and horizonless solutions dubbed fuzzballs. The extra dimensions regularize the singularities, replacing it with a smooth manifold. You can have an intuition of this process by lifting 4d to 5d: in radial coordinates you could have an extra compact coordinate that is shrinking while going near the region of the would-be black hole, capping off smoothly.

On the other hand it is possible to have singular solutions in higher dimension, for instance the  Schwarzschild black holes generalize in Nd trivially to a Schwarzschild-Tangherlini solution, with a singularity and a N-2 dimensional hypersurface horizon.